# Goodness-of-fit for fixed effect logit model using 'bife' package

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression, goodness-of-fit, log-likelihood

I am using the 'bife' package to run the fixed effect logit model in R. However, I cannot compute any goodness-of-fit to measure the model's overall fit given the result I have below. I would appreciate if I can know how to measure the goodness-of-fit given this limited information. I prefer chi-square test but still cannot find a way to implement this either.

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------                 
    Fixed effects logit model                   
    with analytical bias-correction                 

    Estimated model:                    
    Y ~ X1 +X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 | Z                   

    Log-Likelihood= -9153.165                   
    n= 20383, number of events= 5104                    
    Demeaning converged after 6 iteration(s)                    
    Offset converged after 3 iteration(s)                   

    Corrected structural parameter(s):                  

        Estimate    Std. error  t-value Pr(> t) 
    X1  -8.67E-02   2.80E-03    -31.001 < 2e-16 ***
    X2  1.79E+00    8.49E-02    21.084  < 2e-16 ***
    X3  -1.14E-01   1.91E-02    -5.982  2.24E-09    ***
    X4  -2.41E-04   2.37E-05    -10.171 < 2e-16 ***
    X5  1.24E-01    3.33E-03    37.37   < 2e-16 ***
    ---                 
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1                  

    AIC=  18730.33 , BIC=  20409.89                     


    Average individual fixed effects= 1.6716                    
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Exactly what kind of goodness-of-fit measures are you after? It's possible to extract residuals from `bife` objects and you may also estimate different specifications. So you are not so restricted after all.

Comment: Julius Vainora: I prefer chi-square test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let the DGP be

```
n <- 1000
x <- rnorm(n)
id <- rep(1:2, each = n / 2)
y <- 1 * (rnorm(n) > 0)
```

so that we will be under the null hypothesis. As it says in `?bife`, when there is no bias-correction, everything is the same as with `glm`, except for the speed. So let's start with `glm`.

```
modGLM <- glm(y ~ 1 + x + factor(id), family = binomial())
modGLM0 <- glm(y ~ 1, family = binomial())
```

One way to perform the LR test is with

```
library(lmtest)
lrtest(modGLM0, modGLM)
# Likelihood ratio test
#
# Model 1: y ~ 1
# Model 2: y ~ 1 + x + factor(id)
#   #Df  LogLik Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
# 1   1 -692.70                     
# 2   3 -692.29  2 0.8063     0.6682
```

But we may also do it manually,

```
1 - pchisq(c((-2 * logLik(modGLM0)) - (-2 * logLik(modGLM))),
           modGLM0$df.residual - modGLM$df.residual)
# [1] 0.6682207
```

Now let's proceed with `bife`.

```
library(bife)
modBife <- bife(y ~ x | id)
modBife0 <- bife(y ~ 1 | id)
```

Here `modBife` is the full specification and `modBife0` is only with fixed effects. For convenience, let

```
logLik.bife <- function(object, ...) object$logl_info$loglik
```

for loglikelihood extraction. Then we may compare `modBife0` with `modBife` as in

```
1 - pchisq((-2 * logLik(modBife0)) - (-2 * logLik(modBife)), length(modBife$par$beta))
# [1] 1
```

while `modGLM0` and `modBife` can be compared by running

```
1 - pchisq(c((-2 * logLik(modGLM0)) - (-2 * logLik(modBife))), 
           length(modBife$par$beta) + length(unique(id)) - 1)
# [1] 0.6682207
```

which gives the same result as before, even though with `bife` we, by default, have bias correction.

Lastly, as a bonus, we may simulate data and see it the test works as it's supposed to. 1000 iterations below show that both test (since two tests are the same) indeed reject as often as they are supposed to under the null.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I know how the degrees of freedom is extracted to be used in glm but not sure how it works the same for bife function's length(modBife$par$beta) you specified. If I am trying to just take out the loglikelihood values simply to input in the pchisq function without using any buildup function you hypothetically created, from which part shall I take out the values for length(modBife$par$beta)?

Comment: The vector `modBife$par$beta` contains all the beta coefficients (not fixed effects, no intercept). When testing `modBife0` (full model) vs. `modBife` (only fixed effects), it is exactly those beta coefficients that we set to zero. So, if I understand your question correctly, `length(modBife$par$beta)` in the the regular output would correspond to the number of variables: 5 in your example (`X1`, ..., `X5`).

Comment: I'll also jump ahead to explain `length(modBife$par$beta) + length(unique(id)) - 1`. Here we are testing the full model against only the intercept. Then the reason for `length(modBife$par$beta)` remains the same. Next, we set all the fixed effects to zero, and there are `length(unique(id))` of them. But in the full model we also don't have the intercept. So, from `length(unique(id))` non-beta coefficients we go to 1 (intercept), hence the `length(unique(id)) - 1` degrees of freedom.

Comment: Thank you. If length(unique(id)) goes to 1 as it is the intercept as you said and subtract 1 again to get the degrees of freedom, wouldn't that be again length(modBife$par$beta) itself as before? If so, I think the answers should be the same?

Comment: In my example, for instance, we have a1*id1 + a2*id2 + b1*x in the full model (where a1 and a2 are fixed effects, id1 and id2 are individual dummy variables). Then the minimal model would be just intercept*1. So, the number of degrees of freedom = 2 = 1 (beta) + 2 (fixed effects) - 1 (intercept is coming back). In other words, while there are `length(unique(id))` fixed effects, we lose one degree of freedom due to the restriction that all those dummy variables always sum to 1.

Comment: My id (so called Z in my example) is not part of my regressors. It is treated as time variable which is not included in any beta coefficients' measures. When I run length(regress$par$beta) over my model called 'regress' as in my example above, I get 5. However, as you can see from my example, the Z which corresponds to id what you make is not included in the regressors. So if I run on the null model that sets Y~1, using  length(unique(Z)) I get 207 which does not make any sense. Or it make sense to you?

Comment: Anyway what ever it is, I get 0 if I follow your bottom method which seems to be a good sign. Then I just would like to check whether ((-2 * logLik(modGLM0)) - (-2 * logLik(modBife))) is indeed the chi-square value I can report. For my case I get 2711.83
 for this chi-square value and wonder whether this can be ok to report. Probably length(unique(Z))  = 207 makes sense then.

Comment: Then lastly may I know how I can get the R2 value for this as well please?

Comment: Anyway I think length(unique(Z))=207 can make sense since my unique id length is indeed 207 although Z is not part of my regressors as in your bife example above while you put in your glm example with a plus sign as part of the regressors.

Comment: @Eric, re 1st comment: `length(unique(Z))` being 207 should make sense (I'll add test simulation results today or tomorrow in this case). Re 2nd comment: right, that's a value to report, and indeed chi square takes larger value with more degrees of freedom. My id is just like your Z: they are fixed effects (dummy variables for each individual or, in your case, each time period) with estimated values given at `modBife$par$alpha`. Re R^2: in logistic regression there no longer is a clear R^2; there are multiple proposals. One is McFadden's R^2, given by `c(1- logLik(modBife) / logLik(modGLM0))`.

Comment: @Eric, coming back to `length(unique(Z))`, everything is fine, except you need to keep in mind the ratio `n / length(unique(Z))`. The larger it is the better. Otherwise the test may perform poorly.

Comment: Thank you so much again Julius!

Comment: Your second bife models yields the warning "Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "x", value = raw(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 1000" Was there an update due to which this code doesn't work anymore?

Comment: @PeterPan, apparently yes.

Comment: @JuliusVainora alright, lets give the authors some time, its still pre-version 1. Maybe the now omitted statistics show up in the next update again :)